# How should I add code numbers accordingly in front of the items of a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file like this:

Company

Google

Amazon

Facebook

I want to add code number in front of the company names, like:

Company

12 Google

34 Amazon

56 Facebook

How should I do this task by using python?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? By asking a question we're expecting you to have at least thought up of an answer to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built in csv library. There are basic tutorials all over the web on how to access csv files with it and use it, I would recommend https://realpython.com/python-csv/

Essentially, all you need to do is open your file in write form ('w' or 'w+') and iterate over each line. At each line you can use pythons' random number generator module, or use your own list of numbers to put before each string: line[0] = str(randNum) + " " + line[0].

Comment: Likewise with a `pandas` `DataFrame`